# How to send data from MQTT to AMQP

Tags: java, rabbitmq, mqtt

Thanks In Advance!

I have Mqtt installed on Raspberry-Pi and publishing sensor data to mqtt on port 1883. Using Paho client published data is verified on receiver side.

Now i Have RabbitMQ installed on Windows7. How do i send data from mqtt to rabbitmq.

```
String brokerUrlRpi_Mqtt = "tcp://localhost:1883";
String clientId="ExamplePublish";
String channel = "SensorIntegratedData";
int qos=0;

public void publish(String data) throws MqttPersistenceException, MqttException {
  String time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
  System.out.println("Publishing at: "+time+ " to topic \""+channel+"\" qos "+qos);
  MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(data.getBytes());
  message.setQos(qos);
  message.setRetained(false);
  client.publish(channel, message);
  // Disconnect the client
}
```

Mqtt Connection is made dafault without credentials. Now How can i send data to RabbitMQ.

Comment: What have you already tried? Also what do you mean you have "installed MQTT"? I assume you mean you have installed a MQTT broker, most likely mosquitto

Comment: Yes Right! I mean Mosquitto broker is installed on R-Pi. Im trying to send Ultrasonic sensor data to mqtt. Using eclipse paho client i check published data get received.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a MQTT bridge. You can configure the mosquitto instance on your pi to connect to the RabbitMQ broker (assuming it is configured to support MQTT).

Details of how to configure bridges can be found in the mosquitto.conf man page [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/mosquitto.conf.5.html#contenttoc7).

Basically you need to add something like the following to your config.

```
connection rabbitmq
address ip-of-rabbitmq
cleansession true
topic # out 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but It's not working, IP address i have given of windows7 wifi details IPV4 address and "topic # both 0 /"

Comment: You are 100% sure that your RabbitMQ is set up with MQTT support?

Comment: Hmmm, I have enabled plugins and made connections using java api amqp client. Following properties i have set , Username(default guest), Password(guest), setVirtualHost("/"), setHost( ipv4 address of windows), setPort(5672).

Answer (score 0):

Enable mqtt plugins on rabbitmq by running command from command prompt 
OPen cmd prompt path to rabbitmq/sbin default wiil be C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.9\sbin in windows then run command.

"rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt"

We need to set Topic, url of server system on which rabbitmq is running.
send random clientId.
set Qos to either 0 OR 1 OR 2

`String topic = "amq.topic";
String brokerUrlRpi_Mqtt = "tcp://192.168.xxx.xxx:1883/";
String clientId=UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

Username and password should be new user created in rabbitmq, if you send mqtt data from different system. 
If mqtt and rabbitmq are running locally then guest username and password is ok.

`

```
public  SendDataUsingMQTT() throws MqttException {
            String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
//          MqttDefaultFilePersistence dataStore = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(tmpDir);
            try {
              conOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
              conOpt.setUserName("username");
              conOpt.setPassword(new String("password").toCharArray());
              conOpt.setCleanSession(true);
            client = new MqttClient(brokerUrlRpi_Mqtt,clientId, datastore);

 client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() { 

// add all anonymous implemented methods of connect
 public void messageArrived(String arg0, MqttMessage arg1) throws Exception {

//
}
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) { }
 public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {}
}
catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Unable to set up client: "+e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
          }               
          }
```

'